# MariaDB command line stops being responsive after some time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm running MariaDB's (version: `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.12-MariaDB`) `mysql` command to interact with the database. I'm using that multiple times a day, so I just leave window running that console open and come back to it whenever I need it.

The problem is that after some time of my inactivity (let's say 1 hour), when I come back to the console window it's totally unresponsive. I enter commands and don't get any feedback, not even an error - the console is simply dead.

I assume it's some timeout that kills the connection after some time of inactivity.

How can I fix that?

- Is there a way to disable that behavior (timeout)?
- Is there a way for console to at least print me some error message and qui instead of becoming dead?
- Is there a way for the console to auto connect even after losing connection?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable that behavior (timeout)?

Disabling is most likely a bad idea, if applications does not close the connection, the connection keeps active.  
It might even disallow connections from normal MySQL users when the max_connections limit is  reached, I believe MySQL users with SUPER privilege are still able to connect then.

You can use

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 28800
```

for your SQL IDE's connections

For shell/console mysql application

```
mysql [options] --wait-timeout=28800
```

Which sets `wait-timeout` at MySQL's default config off 8 hours see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: MariaDB `mysql` command doesn't accept `--wait-timeout` argument, nor does `SET SESSION wait_timeout = 28800` work inside the database - running it prints `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.085 sec)`.